# Effect of one lightning on its consecutive lightning

Tags: electricity, lightning

When lightning strikes several times in one area, I wonder if the first lightning strike affects the next lightning. For example, when lightning strikes a point $A$, does the next lightning have a relatively higher probability of hitting the same point?

Comment: Instead of providing an answer (without adding anything that already exists online) I suggest this link: https://www.weather.gov/safety/lightning-science-dart-leaders

Comment: I remember watching on YouTube saying that lightning takes the path where it is easier to ionise so that explain the zagged appearance instead of straight line ;D

Comment: @user6760 Branching of leaders, streamers or generally lightning flashes still has no satisfactory explanation in the scientific, i.e., gas discharge community